# Get LastWriteTime of a decimal value

Tags: c#

What is the date of a value lastwritetime like this 347681594.3 ? This doesn't look like a epoche right ?

Comment: How are you obtaining this value? Any of the functions in the .NET Framework that return such a value should return a `DateTime` structure, not an floating point value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is datetime in OA format. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) for more information.
To Convert this into DateTime use following code.

```
DateTime.FromOADate(347681594.3)
```